# Jmeter Unable to load class com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventDataBatch

Tags: jmeter

I have JMeter 5.2.1 installed in my system.
When I try to execute below code i am getting this error.

Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventDataBatch due to missing dependency org/apache/qpid/proton/amqp/messaging/Section

Code:
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.*

```
final String connectionString = 'EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING'
final String eventHubName = 'EVENT HUB NAME'

// create a producer using the namespace connection string and event hub name
EventHubProducerClient producer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
    .connectionString(connectionString, eventHubName)
    .buildProducerClient()

// prepare a batch of events to send to the event hub
EventDataBatch batch = producer.createBatch()
batch.tryAdd(new EventData('Fifth event'))

// send the batch of events to the event hub
producer.send(batch)

// close the producer
producer.close()
```

Below are dependent libraries that i have it in LIB folder. Can you please let me know if i am missing any dependency or using wrong version
dependency.
amqp-client-5.7.1.jar
azure-core-1.13.0.jar
azure-core-amqp-2.0.2.jar
azure-core-test-1.5.3.jar
azure-eventhubs-3.2.2.jar
azure-identity-1.2.3.jar
azure-messaging-eventhubs-5.5.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
jackson-core-2.9.9.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar
jackson-dataformat-xml-2.9.9.jar
jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.9.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.9.jar
junit-jupiter-api-5.6.3.jar
junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar
junit-jupiter-params-5.6.3.jar
mockito-core-3.3.3.jar
proton-j-0.31.0.jar
qpid-proton-j-extensions-1.2.1.jar
reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar
reactor-core-3.3.12.RELEASE
reactor-test-3.3.12.RELEASE
slf4j-api-1.7.28
stax2-api-3.1.4
woodstox-core-5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The `org/apache/qpid/proton/amqp/messaging/Section` lives in [proton-j-0.33.4.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.qpid/proton-j/0.33.4)

I don't know where did you get your `proton-j-0.31.0.jar` from, my expectation is that you should stick to [Microsoft Azure Client Library For Event Hubs » 5.5.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-messaging-eventhubs/5.5.0) and use dependency management system like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) in order to obtain the library with all its dependencies including the [transitive ones.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)

Once you obtain them - copy all the .jar files to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation (or other location on [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)) and **restart JMeter to pick up the changes**

Just in case here is how the list should look like:

```
azure-core-1.13.0.jar
azure-core-amqp-2.0.2.jar
azure-messaging-eventhubs-5.5.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar
jackson-core-2.11.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar
jackson-dataformat-xml-2.11.3.jar
jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.3.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.11.3.jar
jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar
netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.35.Final.jar
proton-j-0.33.4.jar
qpid-proton-j-extensions-1.2.3.jar
reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar
reactor-core-3.3.12.RELEASE.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
stax2-api-4.2.1.jar
woodstox-core-6.2.1.jar
```

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities/) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)) as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue, but was getting below error Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.var() is applicable for argument type any help ?

Comment: "any help" will be provided when you show your code, looking into my crystal ball I can see that you call `this.var()` somewhere but I don't have any idea regarding what you're trying to achieve. If you want to work with JMeter Variables you should be using `vars` shorthand without `this` like `vars.put('foo', 'bar')` or `vars.get('foo')`, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details.

Comment: below is the code that i am using in JSR223 Sampler                                          
 String payload = '{"uid": "504a8988-24bf-4738-b594-23e11ec456a6","uitest": "","uidate": ""}'
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(payload)   Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.var() 
is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
 [{"uid": "504a8988-24bf-4738-b594-23e11ec456a6","uitest": "","uidate": ""}]
Possible solutions: eval(java.lang.String),

Comment: i am able to resolve the issue after using JSR223 Pre-Processor